# example of non abelian totally ramified extension

Tags: galois-theory, p-adic-number-theory, class-field-theory, local-field, ramification

I would like to know the example of totally ramified extension which is not an abelian extension.

It is well known that the Galois group of totally ramified extension is solvable. I studied the proof of this statement.

But this statement is obvious if all of totally ramified extension is abelian extension. So there should be examples of the title.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The splitting field of $x^p-p$ for $p > 2$ or the splitting field of $x^4 - 2$ when $p =2$ are examples.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Could you explain more about proof or give me reference?

Comment: What did you try? $\Bbb{Q}_2(2^{1/3})/\Bbb{Q}_2$ is not Galois, @user902362 gave some Galois examples that are non-abelian.

Comment: But, @reuns , The extension $\Bbb Q_2(2^{1/3})\supset\Bbb Q_2$ is not totally ramified. Replace “$2$” by “$3$’ everywhere and get the kind of extension OP wants.

Comment: @Lubin ??? It is totally ramified ($v(\pi_K)/v(\pi_L)=[L:K]$) and its normal closure is not.

Comment: Oh, I was assuming Galois closure automatically involved; sorry, @reuns . I figured from the tenor of OP’s question that they were assuming that too.