# the splitting field of $x^3-3$ over $\mathbb{Q}_3$

Tags: galois-theory, p-adic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I would like to know the splitting field of $x^3-3$ over $\mathbb{Q}_3$.

・$x^3-3$ has no solution in $\mathbb{Q}_3$ by hensel lemma.

・I don't know how to find $3$ roots in algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_3$.

・This must be subgroup of symmetric group $S_3$ because change of roots are subgroup of $S_3$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: correction: should be 'splitting' field

Comment: It has no solutions in $\mathbb{Q}_3$, you're probably misapplying Hensel's lemma. You need $x^3-3 \equiv 0 \mod 3$ and its derivative $3x^2 \not \equiv 0 \mod 3$ if you are to use it in the simplest case, which doesn't work when $x=0$. Specifically we know if $x$ is a solution then $|x|_3 = 3^{-1/3}$ which is not a permissible 3-adic absolute value in $\mathbb{Q}_3$.

Comment: What would the splitting field of this polynomial over $\Bbb{Q}$ look like? Then prove that you need to adjoin similar ($\approx$ the same) elements to $\Bbb{Q}_3$ as well. As explained in comments to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4088145/11619) the splitting field is totally ramified with Galois group $S_3$.

Comment: use the valuation ($v(3)=1$): $v(3^{1/3})=1/3$ and (if $\theta$ is a primitive 3rd root of 1) $v(\theta-1)=1/2$. As a result the degree of the extension is 6.

Comment: Side note: Hensel's lemma doesn't really ever prove that solutions *don't* exist. I would simply say $x^3-3$ has no solution in $\Bbb Q_3$ because it has no solution modulo $3^2$.

Comment: What do you mean with **find** 3 roots in algebraic closure? We don't find roots, we construct them, by looking at extensions of the form $K[x]/(f) \ \ / K$ with $f\in K[x]$ irreducible.